# Using RewriteMap Lookups in a RewriteCond . Possible?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, rewrite, apache-2.4

I am trying the following

```
RewriteMap lookup "txt:D:/lookup.txt"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/${lookup}
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /a/$1/b/$2.html [PT,L]
```

I am trying to compare if the request path is starting with the valid paths or not.

I have a long list of paths in the lookup file.

Please help on this.

Comment: Anyone please ?

Comment: Maybe you shoud specify the `LookupKey` : `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/${lookup:$1}`

Comment: I have tried that approach but could not get it to work

Comment: Can you provide a sample (few lines) of your `lookup.txt` file ?

Comment: The lookup file looks like this /abc/ abc

Comment: The issue is that ^/${lookup:$1} is not at all resolving

Comment: Could you explain more what is the result you expect ? I mean, typing `http://domain.com/abc` what is the rewrite you want ?

Comment: If the URL starts with http://domain.com/abc/... , apply the rewrite rule for [PT].

Comment: Last comment before entering chat : i know, this was not my question. My question is : what is the target URL you expect ? (e.g : `http://domain.com/a/abc/b/abc.html`)

Comment: Pass through /abc/anypage -> /a/abc/b/anypage.html

Comment: Did you find any solution for it?. I tried many methods with no luck

Answer (score 6):

I've discovered that you cannot have a variable in the `RewriteCond` regex, because it seems it is only compiled once, but not per-request.

You could workaround this by putting both `${lookup}` and `%{REQUEST_URI}` in a test string using a separator (let's say a comma) and then make sure they are equal, e.g :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI},/${lookup:/$1/}/$2 ^([^,]+),\1
```

---

Also note that, for this given sample URL `http://mydomain.dom/abc/mypage.html` :

```
%{REQUEST_URI} = /abc/mypage.html
```

but

```
${lookup:$1} = abc
```

So `%{REQUEST_URI}` will never be equal to `${lookup:$1}`.

To make them equal when requested, you have to :

- enclose `${lookup:$1}` with `/` to get `/abc/` = `/${lookup:$1}/`
- add `$2` to also get the requested file : `/abc/mypage.html` =
  `/${lookup:$1}/$2`
- As your key is `/abc/` (and not `abc`) you need to enclode `$1` with `/` to match the
  key : `/${lookup:/$1/}/`

---

So finally you will have this :

```
RewriteMap lookup "txt:/var/www/lookup.txt"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI},/${lookup:/$1/}/$2 ^([^,]+),\1
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /a/$1/b/$2 [R=301]
```

Going to `http://mydomain.dom/abc/mypage.html` gives me the following log :

```
(1) pass through /a/abc/b/mypage.html
```